# Why is there an infinite loop in the File System on a Mac? /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD

Tags: filesystem

While playing around with `find` in Terminal I came across this odd behavior:
There seems to be an infinite loop in the Mac File System like so:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/
```

...and so on.

Apparently it is possible to access `Volumes` and `Macintosh HD` over and over again.

How is this possible? Should this not confuse any process digging recursively through the File System?

Comment: You said, "_While playing around with find..._", please add the exact `find` _command_, to your post, you were using to cause this loop.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the specific command. I'm simply startled by the fact that `pwd` can produce the following output: 
`/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Volumes/`

Comment: `find` just pointed me to this because I tried to search only on my `Macintosh HD` and then realized that I got output from other volumes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/Volumes/<startup> is simply a symlink, and there's no rules against where you can link.

```
$ ls -la /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     1B 22 Feb 15:40 /Volumes/Macintosh HD -> /
```

It's not an actual infinite loop, only a loop of links; once followed, you're put back up the path.

Comment: Thanks! I guess what confused me was the output of `pwd`. It would make sense if that shortened the path.